# iOS 11 safe areas vs. UIView animation

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, ios11, iphone-x

Consider the following: I've made a reusable UIView subclass which has a background, and some content laid out in its subviews. As the responsible developer I am, I've aligned the view's subviews based on its safe area, so that it will automatically inset its contents when necessary (e.g. on iPhone X):

[image: center vs bottom]

Excellent! The inner view goes edge-to-edge when it's inside the safe area, and insets its content from the bottom when it hangs out of the safe area.

Now let's say that initially the view should be off-screen, but when the user taps somewhere in my app, I want my view to animate to the center of the screen, and it should animate out on a second tap. Let's implement it like this:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    UIView* _view;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(animate:)]];
}

- (void)animate:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    if (_view == nil) {
        _view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        _view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;

        UIView* innerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 90, 90)];
        innerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        innerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;

        [_view addSubview:innerView];
        [_view addConstraints:@[[_view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:innerView.topAnchor constant:-5],
                                [_view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:innerView.rightAnchor constant:5],
                                [_view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:innerView.bottomAnchor constant:5],
                                [_view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:innerView.leftAnchor constant:-5]]];

        _view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                   self.view.bounds.size.height + _view.bounds.size.height / 2);
        [self.view addSubview:_view];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            _view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                       self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
        }];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            _view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                       self.view.bounds.size.height + _view.bounds.size.height / 2);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [_view removeFromSuperview];
            _view = nil;
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

So, now if we launch the app and tap on the screen, this happens:

[image: animate in]

So far so good. However, this is what happens when we tap it again:

[image: animate out]

As you can see, even though the view goes completely outside of the superview's bounds, the safe area insets still get set as if it was at the bottom of its superview.

We can make the effect less abrupt by calling `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` in the animation block in which the view is animated out, but it doesn't eliminate the problem – the bottom space will just grow in an animated fashion instead of expanding abruptly:

[image: better, but still bad]

This is still not acceptable for me. I want it to slide out exactly like it slid in, with 5pt padding on all sides.

Is there a way to achieve this without adding flags like `shouldAlignContentToSafeArea` or `shouldAlignContentToBounds` to my view?

I just want it to work automatically, but work *correctly*...

Comment: 100% agree this is unexpected behavior and seems like it contradicts the documentation for safeAreaLayoutGuide that "if the view is not currently installed in a view hierarchy, or is not yet visible onscreen, the layout guide edges are equal to the edges of the view." Using your example, and simply placing the _view outside the view's bounds with no animation, I can see that the safeAreaLayoutGuide's bottom guide is still 34.

Answer (score 0):

Too easy solution. Try this and see (set center of inner view equal to animating view center - `innerView.center = animatingView.center;`)

```
@interface ViewController () {

     UIView* animatingView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self setupAnimate];
}

- (void)setupAnimate {

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(animate:)]];
}

- (void)animate:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    if (animatingView == nil) {
        animatingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        animatingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;

        UIView* innerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 90, 90)];
        innerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        innerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;

        [animatingView addSubview:innerView];
        innerView.center = animatingView.center;

        animatingView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                   self.view.bounds.size.height + animatingView.bounds.size.height / 2);
        [self.view addSubview:animatingView];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            animatingView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                       self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
        }];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            animatingView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                       self.view.bounds.size.height + animatingView.bounds.size.height / 2);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [animatingView removeFromSuperview];
            animatingView = nil;
        }];
    }
}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Comment: This wouldn’t respect the safe area when the view is positioned to the bottom of the screen. Maybe I wasn’t clear, but I want to respect the safe area insets in general. But if I’m animating the view out of the screen I don’t want the safe area insets to affect my content unless the animation ends with the view overlapping the safe area insets. In my example the view is animated out of the parents bounds, so the safe area insets shouldn’t be applied...